# smssend giving permission error on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, permissions, centos

I am trying to send a sms on Centos 7. I am using a com port modem that is configured, and I have installed smstools. However when I try to send a sms using this command:

```
smsend 0522222222 'testing'
```

I get the following error:

```
smsd: Cannot handle /var/spool/sms/outgoing/send_uAVscJ: Access denied. Check the file and directory permissions.
```

I have checked the internet and I see there are bugs listed. Has anyone found a work around? I see one post suggested to edit the sendsms script but I cannot do so using vi or nano.

I also changed owner to smstool:root and change folders to 777 permissions just to test but it didn't make a difference.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer on a Russian site, I have to change user in

```
/usr/bin/smssend/
```

with nano by running this command

```
#smsd_user="smsd"
smsd_user="smstools"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should login with the `smstools` user account:

```
su smstools
```

And then send the SMS:

```
smstools@localhost$ smsSend 0522222222 'testing'
```